# How can I find the Neo4J Index Key's for Indexes created on nodes using Spring Data?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have created nodes using Spring using the following basic process (see below).  I have a POJO for my Concepts and using this object and a Neo4J template to create nodes with indexes.  I am still unable to discover what the 'KEY' for the created index is.  I know the name of the index is 'CID' but assumed the 'KEY' would be 'conceptId'.  However, when I use the following query (see below), no data is returned.  It is confirmed that the Index does exist, but I am unable to find out what the proper 'KEY' for said index is so I can utilize it to improve query performance.  I am able to query a specified node using WHERE clause searching for a specific value for a property of said node.  However, when I try to find the node using the Index 'CID' with Key 'conceptId' no nodes are returned.

```
// Concept POJO

    @NodeEntity
    public class Concept {

    @GraphId
    private Long nodeId;
    @Indexed(indexName="CID", fieldName="conceptId")
    private Long conceptId;
```

...

```
// service where code to create Concept Nodes exists

    @Repository
    public class ConceptService {

    @Autowired
    private Neo4jTemplate n4jTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private ConceptRepository cr;

// Call to create node in a 'service'

     public void addConceptNode(Concept concept) {

             concept = n4jTemplate.save(concept);
    }
```

...

```
//Cypher Queries used to retrieve nodes using index
START a=node:CID( conceptId = "66573009")
RETURN a;
// this returns 0 nodes quickly

START a=node:CID( conceptid = "66573009")
RETURN a;
// this returns 0 nodes quickly

START a=node:CID( CID = "66573009")
RETURN a;
// this returns 0 nodes quickly

START a=node:CID( cid = "66573009")
RETURN a;
// this returns 0 nodes quickly

START a=node:CID( CONCEPTID = "66573009")
RETURN a;
// this returns 0 nodes quickly

// Cypher query not using index to retrieve same node
START a=node(*)
WHERE HAS(a.conceptId) AND a.conceptId = 66573009
RETURN a;
// this returns 1 node in 77365ms

//'quickly' = approx.(43-87ms).
```

There is more to the code than what is shown, but this gives you the basic gist of how I am creating nodes with indexes in a Neo4J DB.  There are more properties and more indexes.  When using Spring to retrieve the nodes it seems to 'auto' use (I am assuming it is using the index) the index created because it returns the results faster than using the Neo4J data browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you retrieve nodes from index with repository methods, i.e. `conceptRepository.findByPropertyValue` and the like?
I don't remember assigning `fieldName` when annotating fields for indexing, have you tried without parameters to the annotation (or: do you have a minimal indexing setup that works)?

Comment: Yes, I can access the nodes using the exact methods.  It is only using cypher directly that I am unable to access the node using the Index.  I have tried it both ways with and without declaring the fieldName.  Same result.  I did find that fieldName is not necessary for what my end goal is.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, are you possibly querying a numeric index for a `String` value? Just noticed that the indexed field is a `Long`. If you drop the quotes around the value (in fact, as you do in the `WHERE` clause in the query that does work)...

Comment: No, I've tried it several different ways.  It actually sends an error rather than returning 0 rows.  With the quotes I get 0 rows returned, but there should be one row returned.

Comment: Hmm. What error do you get without the quotes? Some thoughts: 1) I don't believe it's possible to retrieve info from a node about how it is indexed (may change with 2.0 Labels and new indexing). 2) The index key ought to be the field name, as you say. 3) The index ought to be numeric absent `numeric=false` parameter in the annotation (since you find it in your last query, the property is numeric, and the index value should be as well). 4) Can you try debugging with breakpoints in places where SDN does lookups in index and look for how its done?

Comment: I have know what the Index Key's are now.  They are the property names used, so in my cause it would be conceptId.  Using the indexes in Spring Data isn't the problem.  The issue is when trying to use Cypher to query to the data. 'START a=node:CID( conceptid = "66573009")
RETURN a; // Error: Invalid query
//string literal or parameter expected
//"START a=node:CID( conceptid = 66573009)"'